# How to grant access permissions to certain files in a folder in Windows server

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2008-r2

There exists a folder in my system with a number of files in it. SYST is a user of the folder with all permissions. SYST had access to all files of the folder. But somehow, now there exists no user named SYST for a number of files in the folder.

How can I grant access permission for SYST to these files in the folder. Granting permission individually to each file is a tedious task.

Is there any other method apart from using icacls?

Comment: If you go to the security tab on the folder, then advanced > change permissions (if newer than XP, 2003) > Replace all child object permissions with.... that will then push the folder level permissions to all files and folders below if that is what you want...

Comment: @CharlesH : Thank you so much. Exactly what I wanted.. But still, The folder is in server and so giving permission this way will be a bit risky it seems. Is there any other option too?

Comment: it is risky as with most permission changes. There are other options but as far as I'm aware your back to icacls which can be tricky...

Comment: @CharlesH : Ok. Thanks for your great help. I just saw certain options like takeown, Set-Acl, etc. similar to icacls. But it seems there also each file is to considered individually.

Comment: Well I know from the folder you could use ' icacls * /grant SYST:(F) ' however I think this recurses so would also affect subfolders and files in subfolders....